# Install client with system.data.sqlclient.dll

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database

I am install an c# winforms app 3.5 to a client that references a mdf file that will in SQL server express.

I installed .net 3.5 sp1 so the latest .net data providers for SQL server should be there??
I am getting an error for system.data and the above dll.  What are the dependencies am I missing?

Comment: Please install a web cam on the machine so we can read the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install SQL Server as well :)
The Dot Net Framework 3.5 does not include SQL Server.

And if its a client deployed application, you should have used a local database, .sdf (SQL Server CE)

.mdf (server based databases) are used when a lot of customers need to access a single shared database.

You can use a .SDF but SQL Server needs to be installed and if the database reside in the application folder you will require to change the connection string as well.